# Firefox does not play MP4

Tags: flash, firefox, video, mp4, explorer

I have two mp4 files in same directory, after clicking on one of my link the

clip is open and playback in same windows.But When i click on the other link,

firefox and explorer always download clip instead playback it.

i experienced same with some of swf files also.

my code is:

`<a href="1.mp4"target="_blank">it be playback</a>

<a href="2.mp4"target="_blank">it be download</a>`

you can see it here

http://sohna.ga/test/test.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firefox cannot open a video file only through a href, it is your addon that is doing it.